# Junit run failed in surefire

Tags: java, maven, junit

I am facing a different problem.I have 5 test classes(junit) in my project and   all of them are  capable of parameterized testing.I can individually test  these classes with eclipse at that time it works perfectly. When I run them  through maven(sure fire),they failed. Error message looks like 
org.junit.runners.Parameterized.parametersMethodReturnedWrongType(Parameterized.java:340). Please help.

code snippet:

```
@Parameters
    public static List<Browser> getBrowserDetails() {
        ConfigReader reader = new ConfigReader();
        return reader.getParameter(ProjectTest.class.getCanonicalName());
    }
```

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.Exception: com.sun.pinna.tests.ProjectTest.getBrowserDetails() must return an Iterable of arrays.
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.parametersMethodReturnedWrongType(Parameterized.java:340)
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.allParameters(Parameterized.java:286)
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.<init>(Parameterized.java:248)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Comment: can you please post your stack trace and the corresponding method of the error message

Comment: Code snippet and stacktrace shared

Comment: I would expect something like that if `reader.getParameter()` returned null. I don't think it's a good design to change what to unit-test depending on external file - should it work or should it not? And config reading should probably have it's own unit test to tell you whether it's working.

Comment: Here only selenium supporting browser details are configured in the config file.

Comment: Can you confirm what it's returning when run with Surfire? It really might be null (due to classpath problems or something), and would produce this result.

Comment: Thanks  Deltharis, the problem was the null value read by the configReader.

Answer (score 3):

```
ProjectTest.getBrowserDetails() must return an Iterable of arrays
```

You have your reason right there. The list your method returns does not contain Arrays but `Browser`objects.

Up to JUnit 4.11 the correct signature of the method would be:

```
public static List<Browser[]> getBrowserDetails()
```

Comment: In junit 4.12 it support collections as parameters.Individually i can run this testclasses using my IDE,No error on that time

Comment: Is there any possibility that sure fire plugin uses any junit dependency <4.12?

Comment: If you are using eclipse you can open the pom.xml and check the `Dependency Hierarchy` tab. There you can see which version of JUnit maven is using.

Comment: You must declare the dependency junit:junit:4.12 in your pom.xml. The Surefire Plugin uses the version that you declare.